# How to return AVG by date and by user

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to perform a task that is quite complicated for me, I need to return the average number of records entered by users per day.

Lets say that i have this table

```
+----+--+---+--------+----------------------+
| id |  |   | random |     insert_date      |
+----+--+---+--------+----------------------+
|  1 |  | 1 | text   | 10/04/2021  00:00:00 |
|  2 |  | 1 | text   | 10/03/2021  00:00:00 |
|  3 |  | 1 | text   | 10/03/2021  00:00:00 |
|  4 |  | 2 | text   | 10/04/2021  00:00:00 |
|  5 |  | 2 | text   | 10/03/2021  00:00:00 |
|  6 |  | 3 | text   | 10/01/2021  00:00:00 |
+----+--+---+--------+----------------------+
```

Expected output

```
+-----+------------+
| avg |    date    |
+-----+------------+
|   2 | 10/04/2021 |
| 1,5 | 10/03/2021 |
|   1 | 10/01/2021 |
+-----+------------+
```

How can I do this with SQL?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
select insert_date,avg(vv) from 
(
select cast(insert_date as Date) as insert_date, count(*) vv
from table 
group by cast(insert_date as Date), user
) tt
group by insert_date
```

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias, cud u help me how to fix it?

Comment: its becasue you just provided dates in your example , i thought they are date type , so please update your question accordingly , see my updated asnwer

Comment: Worked like a charm, ty